# VBA Stop OnTime Function

Tags: vba, ontime

Could someone please help me how to stop the OnTime Function? It doesnt work the way I tried it.

```
Option Explicit

Dim iTimerSet As Double

Public Sub FXKurs_Wahl()
    iTimerSet = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")
    Application.OnTime iTimerSet, "FXKurs_Wahl"
End Sub


Public Sub EndeUhr()        
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime iTimerSet, "FXKurs_Wahl", , False    
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)            
    Call EndeUhr    
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the documentation of the [Application.OnTime method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.ontime)

> Set `Schedule` to `False` to clear a procedure previously set with the same `Procedure` and `EarliestTime` values.

Syntax is `.OnTime(EarliestTime, Procedure, LatestTime, Schedule)`

So if you used

```
Application.OnTime iTimerSet, "FXKurs_Wahl"
```

to start it you need to use

```
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=iTimerSet, Procedure:="FXKurs_Wahl", Schedule:=False
```

to stop it. Note that `iTimerSet` needs to be the same value for both.

Make sure that if you run `FXKurs_Wahl` multiple times you would need to delete multiple `OnTime` procedures. Also make sure there is no other code manupulating the `iTimerSet` value.

---

If it can occur to run `FXKurs_Wahl` multiple times try removing the old one before adding a new `OnTime`

```
Public Sub FXKurs_Wahl()
    EndeUhr 'remove the old one before setting a new one
    iTimerSet = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")
    Application.OnTime iTimerSet, "FXKurs_Wahl"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for your qucik reply!
But isnt that exaclty what I did?
I used
Application.OnTime iTimerSet, "FXKurs_Wahl", , False
to stop it

Comment: @dany2911 How many times did you run `FXKurs_Wahl`? Is there any other code dealing with `iTimerSet`? • Check my edit if that helps.

Comment: There is some more Code in the Sub FXKurs_Wahl(). What I wanted to do is to run that sub every 5 minutes. Since i am using that file for about an hour now it run probably about 12 times. iTimerSet is only used in the two subs above.

Comment: If there is other code in `FXKurs_Wahl` and this code runs longer than the time specified in `TimeValue("00:05:00")` you will get overlapping issues. Can that be your issue? • Does it work if you run `EndeUhr` manually?

Comment: The code in FXKurs_Wahl is quite short therefore, I dont expext there to be overlapping issues. I added you suggestions and will let you know in a couple of minutes if it worked. Thanks so much!